# Unwanted ctrl+h in file saved from man's output

Tags: man, less

After `man less` (and optionally hit `h` for "Summary of less commands"), since `man` uses `less` to display the text, I hit `s` to save the text to a file.

When I open the file in emacs or vi, there are unwanted ctrl+h, and some characters are undesirably repeated. 
Why is that? How shall save "Summary of less commands" correctly?

Why does redirecting the output of `man less` to a file not have the problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That goes back to tele-typewriters (ttys!) in the 70s.

Sending `X<backspace>X` (`^H` being the ASCII BS character) to a tele-typewriter, causes it to write X, go back one character and write X again on top of itself. It being written twice makes it appear as **bold**.

Similarly, for underline, you'd write `_<backspace>X` which would write `X` on top of an *underscore* `X̲`.

`roff`, the typesetting system used by `man` was one of the first thing written for Unix in the 70s as that's how the Unix authors got their funding.

Using `man` then on a tele-typewriter would send those sequences to write bold and underline.

Tele-typewriters soon got replaced with Cathod-Ray-Tube terminals. There, the BS character just moves the cursor backward and characters override the character underneath.

So sending `X<backspace>X` or `_<backspace>X` there just displays `X`. CRTs also have a limited screen space (as opposed to paper in tele-typewriters), so *pagers* like `more` were born.

Pagers were enhanced to understand those `X<BS>X` sequences and use corresponding escape sequences to tell the terminal to display bold or underline.

Nowadays pagers, including `more`, `less`, `most`, `w3m` still understand those sequences.

And `man` still uses them to display bold or underline when the output goes to a pager.

When `man` (at least some implementations) detects that the output doesn't go to a terminal, it doesn't invoke a pager and does not use those sequences, which is why you don't see them when you redirect to a file.

If you want to remove those sequences, you can use the `col -b` command.